# Signed integer overflow during multiplication even when assigning to uint64_t

Tags: c++

noob question - why does this lead to signed integer overflow?

I assume `testNum` is able to accommodate such a big number?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int a = 500000000;
  int b = 5;
  uint64_t testNum = a * b;
  std::cout << testNum << std::endl; 
}
```

I got the following runtime error

```
runtime error: signed integer overflow: 500000000 * 5 cannot be represented in type 'int'
```

There are 2 workarounds I found:

1. Declare a and b as `uint64_t`
2. Insert a 'type cast' in front of `a * b` like `uint64_t testNum = (uint64_t) a * b;`

What I am not sure about is why this code does not work without the workarounds?

Comment: `a*b` is multiplying two `int`s. The result of that expression will be an (32 bit) `int`. You *then* convert it to 64 bit type, but it's already too late.

Comment: Why does `(uint64_t) a * b;` work then? Why isn't it `too late` in this case?

Comment: And why should it? When you multiply two ints you get an int (or you don't, as in this case).

Comment: @LionellLohJianAn Because multiplication between 64-bit and 32-bit is 64-bit. Type case has higher priority than multiplication.

Comment: `(uint64_t)a` is a cast to 64bit unsigned, it won't overflow when multiplied by 5.

Comment: `(uint64_t)a*b` explicitly converts `a` to be `uint64_t`.   Since the expression is now multipying a `uint64_t` (the converted `a`) and an `int` (i.e. `b`), `b` is implicitly converted to `uint64_t` and then the multiplication is done with two operands of type `uint64_t`, producing a result of type `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 7):

`a * b` is done before assigning it to `testNum`, and both `a` and `b` are `int` and the result of multiplying two `int` is an `int`.

For `(uint64_t) a * b;`  the `a` is casted to `uint64_t` and then multiplied by `b`.

As an additional note: in most cases, you want to avoid a c-style case (`(type)`), and instead want to use a cast that explicitly says what cast has to be performed, like `static_cast<uint64_t>(a)`.

Comment: Thanks! 

Regarding "the a is casted to uint64_t and then multiplied by b" -

Is there a reason why the multiplication of a `uint64_t` and an `int` returns an `uint64_t`?

Comment: @LionellLohJianAn - Rules of the language.